# JQuery: Use appendTo() and before() at same time

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a situation that I have a to insert a `div.msg` in a `div.chat-msgs`.

```
<div class="chat-msgs">
  <div class="msg me">How are u?</div>
  <div class="msg">Good, Thanks..</div>
</div>
```

It would be a simple to use `$('div.msg').appendTo($('div.chat-msgs'))`.

The problem occurs that some time I have some other `div`s regarding events like

```
<div class="chat-msgs">
  <div class="msg me">How are u?</div>
  <div class="msg">Good, Thanks..</div>
  <div class="event">XYZ is typing a message</div>
</div>
```

All I want that if any message enter into `div.chat-msgs` it would be at the bottom but above the `div.event`.

```
<div class="chat-msgs">
  <div class="msg me">How are u?</div>
  <div class="msg">Good, Thanks..</div>
  <div class="msg">This is a new message</div>
  <div class="event">XYZ is typing a message</div>
</div>
```

So I was wondering if its possible that we can use `.appendTo()` and `.before()` at the same time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just test if `event` exists:

```
if ($('div.chat-msg').find('.event').length) {
  // exists, use before
} else {
  // doesn't exist, use append
}
```

Comment: That's the exact same thing I just tried. wow. It worked for me thanks.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `insertBefore()` method which is documented [here](http://api.jquery.com/insertBefore/)